# Warehouse for vs Warehouse of

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Can the phrase below have subtle nuances of meaning depending on a preposition?

> 1.Warehouse for raw materials
>
> 2.Warehouse of raw materials

Which phrase implies that the warehouse is full of raw materials? Can we somehow infer that the warehouse is empty or overfull  in one or another case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Warehouse **for** raw materials

Here *for* indicates the intended usage of the warehouse. The purpose of the warehouse is to store raw materials. But we have no idea what is actually in it.

> 2) Warehouse **of** raw materials

Here *of* means *consisting of* or a warehouse with raw materials in it. It is a warehouse with raw materials in it.
In this phrase, the warehouse is not empty, but we cannot tell if it is partly filled or full.